# Доступ к подсети IP камер на клиентской стороне через VPN L2TP

Tags: vpn, l2tp, rules

[image: Текст]

scheme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGFCH.jpg

Подсеть камер : 172.16.1.0

Подсеть VPN сервера : 192.168.1.0

win 10 VPN ip клиента : 172.17.1.11

win 7 VPN ip сервера : 172.17.1.10

Как получить доступ к камерам с VPN сервера?

192.168.1.0 -> 172.17.1.10 (server w7) -> inet -> 172.17.1.11 (client w10) -> 172.16.1.0 (ipcams)

**UPDATE**

> правильно понимаю?
>
> ## win 10
>
> route -p add 172.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.0
>
> route -p add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.17.1.10
>
> route -p add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.0
>
> ## win 7
>
> route -p add 172.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.17.1.11

Comment: Криво нарисована схема. Должно быть, например, 192.168.1.0 -> 192.168.1.1 (server w7) 172.17.1.10 -> inet ...

Answer (score 0):

- На клиенте 192.168.1.x - маршрут к 172.16.1.0 через интерфейс server w7 в подсети192.168.1.0
- На server w7 - маршрут к 172.16.1.0 через 172.17.1.11
- На client w10 - маршрут к 192.168.1.0 через 172.17.1.10
- На камерах - маршрут к 192.168.1.0 через интерфейс client w10 в подсети 172.16.1.0

Это минимум.

Comment: @АлександрЮрьевич Ну и как? читабельно? такие вещи лучше добавлять в текст вопроса с пометкой UPDATE, форматированием и дополнительными пояснениями.